# class with no constructor argument fails to compile when headers and source are separated

Tags: c++

I tried two methods for class creation.

1) Create class in same file as main.cpp and define the class's members functions in same file as main.

2) Create class in a separate (.h) file and define the class's member functions in a separate (.cpp) source file. When I do 1) everything works as predicted. When I do 2) I cannot use the class without passing in an initial value to the constructor, (default constructor) arguments seem to not initialize the code or something. I am really confused why it doesn't work in 2) but it works in 1) when they should be doing the exact same thing.

1) main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dog {
public:
    Dog();
    ~Dog();
    int years_old;
};
Dog::Dog() {
    years_old = 10;
    std::cout << "we are inside dog constructor" << std::endl;
}
Dog::~Dog() {}

int main() {
    Dog dogg;
    cout << "Dog is: " << dogg.years_old << "years old!" << endl;
    cout << "We are in main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

2) 
Dog.h:

```
#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H
class Dog {
public:
    Dog(); // if I pass in arguments both here and in main and in Dog.cpp this works
    ~Dog();
    int years_old;
};
#endif
```

2) Dog.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dog.h"

Dog::Dog() {
    years_old = 10;
    std::cout << "we are inside dog constructor" << std::endl;
};
Dog::~Dog() {
};
```

2) main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dog.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Dog dogg;
    cout << "Dog is: " << dogg.years_old << "years old!" << endl;
    cout << "We are in main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Dog::Dog()", referenced from:
      _main in main-ddbb4d.o
  "Dog::~Dog()", referenced from:
      _main in main-ddbb4d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your constructors.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Counter question: What's your linker command line?

Comment: I don't know enough about the linker. I used `g++ main.cpp && ./a.out` to compile and run

Comment: So use `g++ Dog.cpp main.cpp && ./a.out`

Comment: Wow that works. Yeah I haven't read that anywhere in any of the tutorials/ books I've been using. Any recommended resources for learning?

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You can find that right there in the tag info wiki.